# Jquery EasyUI and <form runat="server"> issues

Tags: jquery, asp.net, c#-4.0, jquery-easyui

I'm trying to build a site that uses a layout from the JQuery EasyUI using .NET with C# 4.0. However, whenever I wrap the site in a  control, the layout is completely screwed up and doesn't display correctly. I imagine it has something to do with the fact that it renders as an actual form tag, and the Javascript being run applies styles to that. I'm not sure exactly how to fix this, especially since I'm not versed well enough in Javascript to begin dissecting the framework's code. Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: If you mix two technologies that are incompatible with each other, such things can be the outcome.

Answer (score 0):

The only thing I can suggest is compare the markup from a working/running copy of EasyUI, to that of your asp.net wrapped version. You'll need to use Firebug or another decent html/css inspector.

It's possible that the base CSS for EasyUI could be modified to include the wrapping .net control, however it sounds like you're in for quite a battle and likely over your head getting it working.

Answer (score 0):

Wow thanks alot for your help guys.

> If you mix two technologies that are incompatible with each other, such things can be the outcome.

Really? That was you helping? Are you really trolling stackoverflow? Get a job.

Anyhow, I removed the class attribute from the body tag, placed the form tag right below it, and added the class to that. I then had to specify a height and width using the style property.

```
<body>
<form runat="server" class="easyui-layout" style="width: 600px; height: 400px;">
```